# About the multiplicative group of a field of prime characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p > 0.$ The claim in a certain lecture notes I am reading is that $F^{\star}$ (the multiplicative group of $F$) has no nontrivial elements of prime-power order. I am struggling to see why. Can you help?

Comment: Do you really mean any prime power? Or rather a power of p? Also, what have you tried so far? Do you know the Frobenius?

Comment: The lecture notes itself wrote prime-power, but I assume the author really meant p-power. I don't know much about the Frobenius other than it is the map taking x to x^p.

Comment: As stated, this is wrong, but given that you are not quoting the lecture exactly, I'm guessing you are misreading it. A simple example is that $-1$ is an element of order $2$ in any field of odd characteristic, and $2$ is a prime power.

Comment: Lecture notes can be a terrible way to learn, because so many specifics can be elided or assumed in lectures, and errors are often not corrected. FWIW

Comment: "... but I assume that..." If you already know the statement is wrong as written, and you are interpreting it another way, please state that in the question, so we don't have to read the comments to help you.

Comment: I genuinely do not "know" and meant "assume" because this is not a subject I am familiar with. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that powers of $p$ are meant, since otherwise it's clearly wrong.

**Hint.** The Frobenius map $x \mapsto x^p$ is injective since it's a field homomorphism.